# .htaccess rewrite redirect based on domain name and request uri

Tags: .htaccess

I am unable to solve a problem for .htaccess.
The requirement is when user visits

- abc.nl/nl_nl/some-content no redirection required.
- abc.nl/fr_fr/some-content it should be redirected to abc.fr/fr_fr

Till now my code is this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the requested uri is  fr_fr
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/fr_fr\/

# But domain is  abc.nl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abc\.nl [NC] 

# Then redirect to abc.fr/fr_fr/what-ever
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ abc\.fr\/fr_fr\/$1 [NC]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below only, in root directory,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fr_fr/(.*)
RewriteRule ^ http://abc.fr/fr_fr/%1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Just a doubt

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?abc.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(nl)_(nl)(.*) 
RewriteRule ^ http://teleroute.%2/%1_%2%3 [R=302]

Here I am getting %1, %2, %3 variables as empty